# how to uglify and minify the the code while creating bundle with meteor build?

Tags: javascript, meteor

With Meteor, how to `uglify` and `minify` ***the server code***?

[Meteor build documentation does not have any configuration related to this.](https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorbuild)

But perhaps there is a internal [meteor package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/minifier-js) contains the code around this.

But readme of this package does not have any documentation again.

So how to achieve the same?

Comment: Which files did you looked into after building? Edit: which OS are you using?

Comment: Using Ubuntu 16.04 - x64. I looked into server/app/myapp.js - this is concatenated, but not uglified nor minified. And also in packages, we have a few private packages that are required to be uglified and minified. and the same behaviour with those packages as well. And its server code that i am talking about.

Comment: This is really weird. If there is no misconfiguration on your side it could also be a bug. Can you add your meteor packages and package.json to the question or a minimum repo using those two files?

Comment: @codeofnode have you ever found a solution? We are still seeing this behavior with Meteor 1.10.x and `meteor build`. That leads to really unnecessarily big bundle sizes and having developer comments in a bundle is also something you sometimes don't want (I also only speak about the server bundle, not the client!).

Answer (score 0):

Meteor minifies JS in production by default. Hence I see no point of using your own package IMO.

> https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html#concatenate-and-minify

Comment: I do `meteor build --directory <my_dest_dir>` and it only concatenates and does not minify. I am still surprised why. And i hope we are concern about the server code, not the browser code.

Comment: The question is how to uglify. Meteor just minifies it but does not uglify